# cmd+w closing window instead of tab

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Chrome Canary and the keyboard shortcut cmd+w is set to close window instead of close tab. How do I change this?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmd+w goes back to closing tabs when I update/relaunch Chrome Canary. There's a button in the top right corner of Chrome when there is an update available.